# Could not find method springBoot() for arguments - Spring Boot using Kotlin

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, kotlin

I try to create the very first Spring Boot application with Kotlin. So, maybe I made some obvious errors or something like that.

My **gradle.build** is:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.5-2'
    ext.spring_boot_version = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

jar {
    baseName = 'rest-voter'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'ru.hixon.Application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.2.RELEASE"
    testCompile 'junit:junit'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.13'
}
```

The **error** is:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\rest-voter>gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Desktop\rest-voter\build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'rest-voter'.
> Could not find method springBoot() for arguments [build_3594if1jtm90vgb7v8evp206i$_run_closure2@459003a0] on root project 'rest-voter'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.351 secs
```

My **main class** is:

```
package ru.hixon

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
open class Application {

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

And [here](https://github.com/Hixon10/simple-kotlin-spring-boot-app) is full code of my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

as well :)

Importing the dependency is not enough.

Comment: it is so strange. I created project, which contained this plugin. Then gradle said, that this plugin is deprecated, and I have to use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin`. Then I removed it. Now I add this plugin, and there is no message about deprecated

Comment: For new spring boot versions you need to use apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' and then add the buildInfo() block below it to avoid build errors.