# Using Gradle in Eclipse - Can't get the -Dspring.profiles.active to take effect

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

Not an expert but Gradle is what the (Spring Boot) project is using. I have a `@Component` which runs setting up dummy data, but I only want it to run locally. So now I have put an `@Profile("local123")` over it too and this turns the component off. Great.

Next I wanted to put in Eclipse's `Run Configurations... > JVM Arguments` the `-Dspring.profiles.active=local123` so that the component is turned on but **only** when I'm running my build locally. No joy. I have seen some posts that say [you need to add this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367507/how-to-pass-system-property-to-gradle-task) or similar to build.gradle

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```

but anywhere I try to add it in the file, it causes my build to crash.

1. Where am I going wrong? *and/or*
2. Where do I get documentation on the structure of build.gradle to work out where this should go!

Comment: You need an `application-local123.properties` file in the same directory as `application.profile`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, I put in a blank application-local123.yml file both with _"Could not find method bootRun() for arguments"_ and without _"Task 'bootRun' not found in root project"_ the bootRun section in build.gradle and neither works.

Comment: why blank, should have the same as the base .properties.

Comment: :( No joy unfortunately. Still giving me: "Could not find method bootRun() for arguments". I was hoping the contents of the application file would be inherited from the default one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40642636/2834978

Comment: Still no joy. Had the `org.springframework.boot` one of those included all along. Included an empty buildInfo{} block but doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: are you sure the error is related to the profile?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Yes, that is the only change I have made. Just adding the [at]Profile annotation, the switch to the VM Args and the sections to build.gradle (though I take them out each time as I don't know if they are right!)